# Stuttering shutter sound

Tags: ios, swift

I am taking a picture within my iOS app by using the following code:

```
self.stillImageOutput.captureStillImageAsynchronously(from: videoConnection) {
    // Do some stuff here
    self.captureSession.stopRunning()
    // Do some more stuff
}
```

For some reason, having that `stopRunning()` call inside the capture block makes the shutter sound stutter. If I remove it, then the shutter sound is perfectly fine. How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: It's just a guess, but shouldn't you call stopRunning() from the main thread?

Comment: maybe you are calling the `-stopRunning()` function twice from two different threads?

Answer (score 3):

You don't want to access the UI asynchronously. Based on what you describe, it sounds like an async block could be the source of the stutter. Two approaches you could try in order to get the main queue to play your sound:

```
// everything is going swimmingly until you play the sound...
// grab the main queue
DispatchQueue.main.async {
// play your sound
}
// and live happily ever after
```

Another approach:

```
// everything is going swimmingly until you play the sound...
// grab the main queue
DispatchQueue.main.suspend()
// play your sound                
DispatchQueue.main.resume()
// and live happily ever after
```

Comment: Ok so I put the first code block around the `stopRunning()` call. This prevents the stutter. However, when I go back to that view (the capture session is restarted), and press the camera button again, the sound stutters again. What could be happening?

Comment: Try putting it around the block (`startRunning()`?), too?

Comment: Hmm actually the stuttering seems to be a bit on and off, now it's still stuttering with the exact same code as when it did.